# wordpress menu - changing <li> class name for dropdown

Tags: wordpress, class, menu, navigation

I was curious if anyone knows how i could do this .. by default wordpress have the sub-menu class on the UL like this...

```
<li><a href="#">Where We Operate</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Russia</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
                                    </ul>
```

Is it possible to change the sub-menu class to the **LI** before the **UL** like this:

```
<li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Where We Operate</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Russia</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
                                    </ul>
```

I have tried a walker class, but all i can change is the UL class.

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"my-sub-menu\">\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want this? There is no logic behind this! You should css this the right way and everything is solved?

Comment: What if you're using bootstrap, which uses a specific class structure for styling menus? You can customize bootstrap, but then you can't update it without re-customizing it.